# Ajax request outputing HTML Code instead of form value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http

As the title says, i have been having a problem with Ajax for 2 days now and can't seem to find why. I looked it up but didn't find a suiting solution.

Here is the code i am using :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test_unity</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    
    .Read_position {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items : center;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #2c3e50;
        margin: 10%;
    }
    
    .DivForm {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .text-align{
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
  
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          console.log("jQuery est prêt !");
        });
    
    
        function ajax_request(){
            console.log("RequeteAjax pos_unity");

            let tmp_x = $('#pos_x').val();
            let tmp_z = $('#pos_z').val();
            console.log(tmp_x + " " + tmp_z)

            $.ajax({            
                url :"get_pos.php",
                type :"POST",
                data : JSON.stringify({
                  pos_x : tmp_x,
                  pos_z : tmp_z 
                }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(text,state){
                    console.log("operation reussi : "+text);
                    alert("tmp : "+text);
                },
                error : function(result, state, error){
                    //alert("resultat : "+result+" / statut "+state+" / erreur : "+error);
                    alert("error : \n" + result.responseText);
                },
                complete : function(result, state){
                  alert("complete : "+result+" / statut "+state);
                  console.log(tmp_x + "/" + tmp_z)
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
    <body>
    <?php
    echo('
      <form class="Read_position" method="post" name="main_form" action=""> 
        <p class="text-align"><b>Envoyer une position a Unity : </b></p>
        <div class="DivForm">
          <label for="pos_x">Position X : </label><input type="number" id="pos_x" name="pos_x">
        </div>
        <div class="DivForm">
          <label for="pos_z">Position Z : </label><input type="number" id="pos_z" name="pos_z">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="entree"style="margin-top:10px;" onclick="ajax_request()">send positions</button>
      </form>
      <br>
    ');
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What i am trying to do with that Ajax request is to get the form value entered by user and display it (for now) in an alert box.

Here's the code from get_pos.php as it has been asked :

```php
<?php

$pos_x = 0;
$pos_z = 0;
$file = "positions_unity.txt";
$error_msg = "ERROR" ;

if( isset($_POST["pos_x"]) && isset($_POST["pos_z"]) ) {
    $data = $_POST["pos_x"]+"/"+$_POST["pos_z"];
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    exit();
} else if(file_get_contents($file) === "" ) {
    file_put_contents($file, $error_msg);
    echo(file_get_contents($file));
    exit();
} else {
    echo(file_get_contents($file));
    exit();
}

?>
```

Here is what is displayed instead by the error function :

```
error :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test_unity</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.Read_position {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items : center;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #2c3e50;
    margin: 10%;
}

.DivForm {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
...
```

Expected output would be whatever the user types in.

If you have any idea please let me know.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Where's the code of `get_pos.php`?

Comment: Unrelated to you actual problem, but why are you echoing your whole from instead of just using the HTML?

Comment: Your button is a submit button, and you did not prevent the default action - so this should be submitting the form the normal way, canceling any AJAX request you might have started, anyway.

Comment: Check the URI, you are probably loading the wrong page. Check if the POST request works alone, using tools like https://www.postman.com/

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Have you checked which request is really sent in your browser's network console?

Comment: Don't use inline onclick handlers and don't use any tutorials that use them. The proper way to handle that form submission is: `$('form.Read_position').on('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* more code here */ });` This will stop the regular form submission, which in your case reloads the document (thanks to the form having no `action` attribute).

Comment: @CBroe i edited the post with get_pos.php code, even tho it's unrelated for this problem.
preventDefault doesn't seem to be a problem here, except for the fact that it reloads the page, but i will fix that.

Comment: @empiric it's an old project made by another intern and i am trying to fix it at the moment. Will change that too, considering it is useless.

Comment: Here's the code with the main and some other issues fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/vz3tmk4r/

Comment: _"even tho it's unrelated for this problem"_ - and with the level of knowledge & debugging skills you are currently showing here, you would be the right person to determine that ..? If your AJAX code goes into the `error` handler, then your server must have responded with an error HTTP status code, or a wrong content type - so _of course_ what happens on the server side, is relevant here. You will need to figure out why it actually errors, but your isset statements there will surely never be true. (Because you are sending JSON, in which case PHP will not populate $_POST in the first place.)

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG i will be checking that !

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CBroe . What i mean by unrelated is because my actual problem is just outputing the input value in an alert box once sent. Of course my knowledge and skills are very limited as i am a beginner.
I changed to JSON after trying to find solutions on other posts, but will change that back to plain text. Thank you very much.

Comment: `my actual problem is`...yes but in order to achieve that, obviously you have to get all the steps leading up to it implemented correctly. It's like a root-cause analysis or diagnosis process. If something doesn't work the way you expect, you trace the path back to where it started to go wrong, which is what CBroe is trying to help you do.

Comment: _"What i mean by unrelated is because my actual problem is just outputing the input value in an alert box once sent."_ - but you are not trying to output the value you are _sending_, you are trying to output the _response_ you get from the server.

Comment: @ADyson Ok thank you, i didn't see it that way.

Comment: @CBroe My bad. Used the wrong terms.

Comment: No problem. But that's the approach you need to follow as a programmer in order to debug your programs, so hopefully that knowledge will help you in future!

Comment: `dataType: "json"` is also likely to hinder you here, because that tells jQuery to expect your server to return data in JSON format and try to parse it. But your PHP code doesn't return JSON, so you might find there's an error message in your browser's Console about that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues occurring here:

1. Not handling the default form submission properly and prevent it in order to launch the AJAX code
2. Sending JSON in the AJAX request but not configuring PHP to expect JSON
3. Sending plain text in the PHP response, but configuring jQuery to expect JSON.
4. In the case where the user submits some data, your code will store them in the file, but not output them again. Currently it's only programmed to output the file contents when no POST values were submitted.

This should sort out all those issues:

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" name="entree"style="margin-top:10px;">send positions</button>
```

(just removed the old-fashioned inline `onlick`)

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('form.Read_position').on('submit', function(e) { //better event handler
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default postback
    console.log($('#pos_x').val() + " " + $('#pos_z').val())
    
    //send normal form data, no JSON in either direction
    $.ajax({
      url: "get_pos.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        pos_x: $('#pos_x').val(),
        pos_z: $('#pos_z').val()
      },
      success: function(text) {
        console.log("operation reussi : " + text);
        alert("tmp : " + text);
      },
      error: function(result, state, error) {
        alert("error : \n" + result.responseText);
      },
      complete: function(result, state) {
        alert("complete : " + result + " / statut " + state);
        console.log(tmp_x + "/" + tmp_z)
      }
    })
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$file = "positions_unity.txt";
$error_msg = "ERROR" ;

if( isset($_POST["pos_x"]) && isset($_POST["pos_z"]) ) {
    $data = $_POST["pos_x"]+"/"+$_POST["pos_z"];
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
} 
else if(file_get_contents($file) === "" ) {
    file_put_contents($file, $error_msg);
}

//always echo the data. HTML-encode it to protect against XSS
echo(file_get_contents(htmlspecialchars($file)));
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you ! The code is way cleaner like that indeed. I still get the HTML code in the success() alert box and console nonetheless. I can't get my head on why that happens.

Comment: Maybe there is some HTML code before the `<?php` tag in your file? If so, you should move this PHP code to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Anyway if the answer has helped you, please remember to mark it as "accepted" and/or upvote it - thanks :-)

Comment: There is actually no HTML at all in the get_pos.php file. All the HTML is in the main file (with the JavaScript code above)

Comment: Also it's a bit weird because using console.log() on either $('pos_x").val() or $('pos_z").val() actually outputs the numbers. But the result differs.

Comment: Those things are both strange, and don't make sense based on what you've shared so far. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure thing !
I typed 444 in pos_x and 222 in pos_z and this is what was outputed in the alert box and console.log() :
tmp : 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test_unity</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.Read_position {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items : center;
 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #2c3e50;
 margin: 10%;
}

.DivForm {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}

.text-align{
...

Comment: The only way that could occur is if there is some other code in get_pos.php (or in a file which get_pos.php includes) which includes or outputs HTML

Comment: Have you checked what's actually in the file on the disk?

Comment: Unfortunately the only file which has HTML code is send_position.php (the main file), get_pos.php only has what i showed (well, what you fixed now i guess) and the only other file is the .txt file which only has the positions (in theory at least, for now it's only "ERROR").

Comment: get_pos.php doesn't receive anything actually, that's another problem. It shows "ERROR" because pos_x and pos_z are undefined for that file.

Comment: If you submitted the data, it should have saved it. Something weird is going on. Check your browser's Network tool and look at the call to get_pos.php when you run the code, and see what values are actually sent in the request.

Comment: I've just tested my jQuery code with your form, and it definitely sends the correct position data.

Comment: That's super weird. the "Headers" part of the network activity says : Form Data pos_x: 444&pos_z: 555. But Response still is the complete file code.

Comment: I didn't test the PHP part, only the AJAX part. That bit worked to send the data, and it sounds like your AJAX worked too, from what you've just told me.

Comment: So for you it actually outputs the values entered in the form ?

Comment: It sends the pos_x and pos_y values in the Form Data bit of the request, like you said. But since I didn't actually send it to a real server it doesn't return anything. That's what I meant when I said I didn't test the PHP part.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. So the problem probably comes from the PHP part.

Comment: Yes, definitely it does.